# jquery val returns jquery function

Tags: jquery

maybe im just to tired but can someone tell me why this is not working? i have this inputfield with the following jquery function.

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" data-catid="1">

$("#search").on("keyup",function(){
var searchid=$(this).val;
var category=$(this).attr("data-catid");
var dataString=searchid;
alert(dataString)  ;})  ;});
```

alert shows me a what i guess is a 200 character jquery function in return

on the other hand he can correctly show the data-catid attribute, so it seems to be specific about .val. This seems so simple but something is obv. wrong....

Comment: You need parentheses to call a function: `$(this).val()`

Comment: `.val` is the function. `.val()` calls the function.

Comment: k sorry, i guess i should have gone sleep few hours ago...obv correct answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change $(this).val to $(this).val()